# How to control relays using Raspberry PI and Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I am using the watch method from the onoff module to watch to status of the input, the callback function will be called for any change in the input (from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0) which is what I want.

The problem is when I first run the application if the main is on (inputMain is 1 ) or the main is off (inputMain is 0 ) the callback function is not executed because there is no change in the value of the input.
So if the main is on I can't call the main() function until it becomes off then on, this problem only happens when I first run the application.

How do I get around this ? Is there a better approach to handle relays ?

```
var GPIO = require('onoff').Gpio,
 inputMain = new GPIO(17,'in','both'),
 inputGen1 = new GPIO(4,'in','both'),
 inputGen2 = new GPIO(27,'in','both'),
 inputGen3 = new GPIO(22,'in','both'),
 outMain = new GPIO(11,'high'),
 outGen1 = new GPIO(15,'high'),
 outGen2P = new GPIO(18,'high'), // Generator 2 power
 outGen2SM = new GPIO(23,'high'), //Generator 2 starting motor
 outGen2 = new GPIO(24,'high'), // Generator 2 contactor
 outGen3P = new GPIO(25,'high'),
 outGen3SM = new GPIO(8,'high'),
 outGen3 = new GPIO(7,'high'),
 objects =[outMain,outGen1,outGen2P,outGen2SM,outGen2,outGen3P,outGen3SM,outGen3];
```

// Checking if there is main or not which is the refrence for all other        power sources

```
 inputMain.watch(function(err,state){
   if (state)
      main(1);
  });
```

//  Switch to Main contactor

```
function main (arg) {
 console.log('test');
 if (arg == 1) {
 value = [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];}
 else {
 value = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
 }
 out(value);

}
```

// Turn on all the  relays depending on values of the array ...

```
function out(value) {

  for ( var i = 0; i< value.length; i++) {

    if (value[i] == 0 )  {
        var a = objects[i];
    } else {

         objects[i].writeSync(value[i]);
    }
 }
    setTimeout(function() {
    a.writeSync(0);
    },5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will need to call read or readSync for that.

```
...
outGen3SM = new GPIO(8,'high'),
outGen3 = new GPIO(7,'high'),
objects =[outMain,outGen1,outGen2P,outGen2SM,outGen2,outGen3P,outGen3SM,outGen3];
//Forces the first output update
main(inputMain.readSync());
```